# Problem of database connection to localhost with FlameRobin/Firebird

Tags: firebird, flamerobin

I'm coming here because I wanted to test some things with Firebird.
Indeed, I need to create a database with LibreOffice Base, which now comes with Firebird-3:
I would like to not have an embedded database in LibreOffice Base, but better connect LO Base to a Firebird file. So that, LibreOffice is just an interface and database management tool.
And as a result, I would get a fdb file that I could access from other applications, such as isql, or FlameRobin.

Here comes my problem: when trying to connect a database through localhost (with both isql and FlameRobin), with the sysbda username and password, I get this error message:

```
isql-fb 
Use CONNECT or CREATE DATABASE to specify a database
SQL> connect localhost:test.fdb user sysbda password mdptestmdp;
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 28000
Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login.
```

or in FlameRobin:

```
*** IBPP::SQLException ***
Context: Database::Connect
Message: isc_attach_database failed

SQL Message : -902
Unsuccessful execution caused by a system error that precludes successful execution of subsequent statements

Engine Code    : 335544472
Engine Message :
Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login.
```

For information,

- when I access the databases not through the localhost server, but with the usual path, it works.
- I changed, checked and re-checked my sysbda username and password.
- I tested with one new user created with right-click on 'localhost' in FlameRobin, and it doesn't change anything.
- I tested with one database fdb file created from the LO Base database creation wizard (connect to a Firebird file), and with a database created within the SQL prompt of the isql-fb tool
- I run on Lubuntu 18.04, with LibreOffice 6.3, and installed Firebird3.0 and FlameRobin from default Ubuntu packages (`sudo apt install flamerobin` and `sudo apt install firebird3*`)

I really don't know how to do... I've try to find out, but did not find any solution for that...
I am still poorly skilled in such computer issue... and have never worked before with server aspects... maybe should I also configure my "localhost"...? (I am connected to internet only through metered 4G).

Please ask me for any further detail that could help to fix that.

**EDIT**
Following your comments, Mark Rorreveel, here are some new informations:

- `connect localhost:test.fdb user sysbda password 'mdptestmdp';` doesn't change anything...
- I checked my username and password in the SYSBDA.password file and they are the indicated ones.
- `#AuthServer = Srp`. Should I remove the #?
- `#AuthClient = Srp, Srp256, Legacy_Auth           #Non Windows clients`.  As well # to be removed?
- `#UserManager = Srp`. As well again to be removed the #?

Comment: The correct statement is `connect localhost:test.fdb user sysbda password 'mdptestmdp';` (that is, password in single quotes). Possibly your password is wrong. Otherwise, please show the settings in firebird.conf of `AuthServer`, `AuthClient` and `UserManager`. Connection strings without a hostname may use Embedded to connect, which doesn't validate credentials because it assumes that if your user has read/write access to the database, it can connect.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation for the connection without a hostname in strings. I just edited my initial post with the expected informations.

Comment: You don't need to remove the `#`, it is commented out, so it will use the defaults (which are as shown).

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that the password wasn't actually set by the installer. If you can connect without specifying the hostname, you could try using `create or alter user sysdba password '<yourpassword>';` and see if afterwards connecting through the hostname will work. That does assume that your embedded access has read/write access to the security database, which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: can he have both FB2 and FB3 installed with race conditions over TCP ports?

Comment: @Arioch'The , I don't think I have FB2 installed, but to be sure, how can I check?

Comment: I think it is better if you take your question to the firebird-support list. We seem to need to many troubleshooting steps, which makes this rather less suitable for stack overflow.

Comment: using netstat or netview or something there is in Linux - check the TCP ports, which firebird or xinet ELF binary is listening for the port you try to connect to. Default Firebird/Internet ports can be seen in the `firebird.conf` file

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ,ok, thanks, I will think of that.

Comment: @Arioch'The , thanks for suggestion, I can't try right know but will test it later.